# Tables in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I would like to know if it is incorrect to use tables for a given article layout in Joomla? By that I mean that if you use tables it is easy to see the layout of the article that you are making.

From Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad practice in web design to use tables for this purpose, these are intended only
 to layout tabular information.

By default joomla! includes [Bootstrap v2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), so you can use the code in this library or
 you can include other library or framework. In this case you can use the **Grid System**:

- Find more info here:
  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Best Regards.